# Jest mock not exported function from another module, Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I want to be able to mock function that is not exported but used in that function that I want to test.
Here is the small code example.

#### file.ts

```
const hello  = () => {
    console.log('hello');
}

export const say = () =>{
    hello  ()
    return 10;
}
```

#### file.test.ts

```
  import {say } from 'file'; 

  describe("Test ", () => {
        it("test", async () => {
            // how to mock hello before that ? 
            say();
            
         
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest has the ability to mock ES module (whole ts/js file), but with your current implementation is impossible to do so.

My suggestion is to extract `function hello` into another file called `hello.ts` and import it for `function say` to use. Then jest can mock the `hello.ts`

Sample code:

```
// hello.ts
export const hello  = () => {
  console.log('hello');
}
```

```
// say.ts
import { hello } from "./hello";

export const say = () =>{
  hello();
  return 10;
}
```

```
// say.test.ts
import { say } from './say';

jest.mock('./hello', () => {
  return {
    hello: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log('mock hello');
    })
  };
});

describe('Test ', () => {
  it('test', async () => {
    // how to mock hello before that ?
    say();
  });
});
```

Output:

[image]